# Building Gelide in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gtk, 18.04

I did a clean install of 18.04, and now I'm unable to build the emulator frontend Gelide.  It has some very old gtk dependencies, and I can no longer downgrade to them. The code looks like it uses some deprecated static methods, and the non-static alternatives don't return the same type. Is there anyone who is familiar enough with gtk to help make the changes necessary to get it to build?  Here's the repo: https://github.com/tapule/Gelide

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first we need to install build-tools and dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential autoconf libtool automake intltool \
libtool-bin libglib2.0-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev libxml2-dev gnome-doc-utils \
rarian-compat
```

Then clone repository

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/tapule/Gelide.git
```

Configure source and compile it:

```
cd Gelide/
./autogen.sh
make
```

This step fails on clean 18.04 LTS I get errors on last stage:

```
config.cpp: In constructor ‘CConfig::CConfig()’:
config.cpp:31:16: error: ‘build_filename’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
  l_cfg = Glib::build_filename(utils::getGelideDir(), GELIDE_CFG_FILE);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
config.cpp:33:11: error: ‘file_test’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
  if(Glib::file_test(l_cfg, Glib::FILE_TEST_EXISTS))
           ^~~~~~~~~
config.cpp:33:34: error: ‘FILE_TEST_EXISTS’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
  if(Glib::file_test(l_cfg, Glib::FILE_TEST_EXISTS))
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
config.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual CConfig::~CConfig()’:
config.cpp:40:13: error: ‘build_filename’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
  save(Glib::build_filename(utils::getGelideDir(), GELIDE_CFG_FILE));
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:612: recipe for target 'config.o' failed
make[2]: *** [config.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mate/Downloads/Gelide/src'
Makefile:553: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mate/Downloads/Gelide'
Makefile:464: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So some patch for this code is needed. I reported [bug to developer](https://github.com/tapule/Gelide/issues/9).

---

But on 16.04 LTS I can move further:

```
sudo make install
```

Running it with `gelide` results in great screeshot:

[image: Gelide on 16.04 LTS]

Comment: I reported [bug to Gelid developer](https://github.com/tapule/Gelide/issues/9).